# Inheritance in Swift is a bit confusing

Tags: swift, inheritance

How does inheritance work in Swift? From my understanding all parents should be replaceable by their children. For some reasons it is not working. Below is an example:

```
public class Car {

var model: String

func getModel()-> String?{
   return model
}
}


 public class CompactCar: Car {
  // some codes

 }

public class carRedo{
 var cartyp:Car!
init(carType: Car){
   self.cartyp = carType
}
}
```

when I pass the CompactCar to carRedo constructor I am getting a compiling error:

```
carRedo(CompactCar)// error
```

This the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(CompactCar).Type' (aka 'CompactCar.Type') to expected argument type 'Car'

Comment: you're just passing a type into an argument that expects an object. You want `carRedo(CompactCar())`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I just noticed my mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass `CompactCar` (or any other class name, for that matter) to the constructor of `carRedo`. You need to pass an *object* of type `CompactCar` instead:

```
let mini = CompactCar()
let redo = carRedo(mini)
```

If you do not need to access the car that you pass to `carRedo` separately, you could "fold" the two calls above into one:

```
let redo = carRedo(CompactCar())
//                           ^^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I just noticed my mistake